# ciclo for no se comporta adecuadamente en javascript para poder agregar al array adecuadamente

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

En este código no logro que la función agregar tarea se comporte adecuadamente pues ser repite la última instrucción al no querer agregar mas nada... quizás seria hacerlo con un while pero no encuentro como...

```
// Presentación
let nombreUsuario = prompt(`Bienvenido a tu To-do list, estoy hablando con...`)

//Definimos las tareas que deben encntrarse en una lista predefinida

let rutinaPredefinida = prompt(`"Abrir mi día" incluye: Hidratarse, meditar y desayuno saludable... \n
"Cerrar mi día" incluye: filtros luz azul, leer y dormir con tiempo...  \n
Si deseas comenzar con "Abrir mi día" escribe 1,\n si deseas "Cerrar mi día" escribe 2,\n si deseas ambas escribe 3,\n Si no quieres ninguna, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

const ABRIRDIA = ["Hidratarse", "Meditar", "Desayunar balanceadamente"]

const CERRARDIA = ["Filtros de luz azul", "Leer", "Dormirse temprano"]

const AMBASRUTINAS = ABRIRDIA.concat(CERRARDIA);

const TODOLIST = []

// Rutinas predefinidas
alert(`${nombreUsuario} ¿Quieres agregar alguna de estas rutinas predefinidas a tus tareas?`)

if (rutinaPredefinida == 1) {
    TODOLIST.push(ABRIRDIA)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 2) {
    TODOLIST.push(CERRARDIA)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 3) {
    TODOLIST.push(AMBASRUTINAS)
} else {
    alert(`Okey! No agregaras ninguna "Rutina predefinida" a tu To-Do List... ¡Adiós!`)
}


// Agregar tareas propias
function agregarTarea() {
    let cantidadTareas = prompt(`A continuación agregue la tarea que desee`)

    for (let i = 0; i < cantidadTareas; i++) {
        let agregar = prompt("Escribe aquí una tarea")
        TODOLIST.push(agregar)

        
    } 

}

agregarTarea()




// Consulta y estado final
let consultaFinal = prompt(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${TODOLIST}! 
Si quieres remover la última tarea escribe: 1 (las rutinas predefinidas se borran todas juntas)
Si quieres agregar una tarea escribe: 2
Si no quieres hacer cambios, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (consultaFinal == 1) {
    TODOLIST.pop()
} else if (consultaFinal == 2) {
    agregarTarea()
} else {
    alert(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${TODOLIST.join("-")}!`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente tu problema esta pasando porque estás siempre ejecutando `agregarTarea` después de definirla.

```
// Agregar tareas propias
function agregarTarea() {
    ...
} 

// Remueve esta línea
agregarTarea()
```

```js
// Presentación
let nombreUsuario = prompt(`Bienvenido a tu To-do list, estoy hablando con...`)

//Definimos las tareas que deben encntrarse en una lista predefinida

let rutinaPredefinida = prompt(`"Abrir mi día" incluye: Hidratarse, meditar y desayuno saludable... \n
"Cerrar mi día" incluye: filtros luz azul, leer y dormir con tiempo...  \n
Si deseas comenzar con "Abrir mi día" escribe 1,\n si deseas "Cerrar mi día" escribe 2,\n si deseas ambas escribe 3,\n Si no quieres ninguna, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

const ABRIRDIA = ["Hidratarse", "Meditar", "Desayunar balanceadamente"]

const CERRARDIA = ["Filtros de luz azul", "Leer", "Dormirse temprano"]

const AMBASRUTINAS = ABRIRDIA.concat(CERRARDIA);

const TODOLIST = []

// Rutinas predefinidas
alert(`${nombreUsuario} ¿Quieres agregar alguna de estas rutinas predefinidas a tus tareas?`)

if (rutinaPredefinida == 1) {
    TODOLIST.push(ABRIRDIA)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 2) {
    TODOLIST.push(CERRARDIA)
} else if (rutinaPredefinida == 3) {
    TODOLIST.push(AMBASRUTINAS)
} else {
    alert(`Okey! No agregaras ninguna "Rutina predefinida" a tu To-Do List... ¡Adiós!`)
}


// Agregar tareas propias
function agregarTarea() {
    let cantidadTareas = prompt(`A continuación agregue la tarea que desee`)

    for (let i = 0; i < cantidadTareas; i++) {
        let agregar = prompt("Escribe aquí una tarea")
        TODOLIST.push(agregar)

        
    } 

}

// Esta línea debes de removerla aquí para que no se ejecute siempre
//agregarTarea()




// Consulta y estado final
let consultaFinal = prompt(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${TODOLIST}! 
Si quieres remover la última tarea escribe: 1 (las rutinas predefinidas se borran todas juntas)
Si quieres agregar una tarea escribe: 2
Si no quieres hacer cambios, escribe cualquier otro valor`)

if (consultaFinal == 1) {
    TODOLIST.pop()
} else if (consultaFinal == 2) {
    agregarTarea()
} else {
    alert(`¡Estas son tus tareas:  ${TODOLIST.join("-")}!`)
}
```

Comment: entonces que tendria que hacer... eliminar agregar tarea o sino ¿como haría?

Comment: Solo elimina esa única linea

Comment: Entiendo que tu intencion es que  "agregarTarea" solo se ejecute si el valor de "consultaFinal" es 2, verdad?

Comment: Exactamente @LeviArista

Comment: Bueno, en todo caso edito mi respuesta dejandote el ejemplo completo solo quitando esa linea.